# Python/FTPlib - return results of FTP transfer?

Tags: python, ftplib

I have a function that transfers a file to an FTP server, is it possible to store the result of the session?

code below:

```
 ....
 with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
  temp.write(content)
  temp.seek(0)
  filename = temp.name
  session = ftplib.FTP('10.66.118.251','build','password')
  session.storbinary('STOR {0}'.format(file_name), temp)
  session.quit()
  temp.flush()
```

i have tried the below to get the results:

```
...  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
...   temp.write(content)
...   temp.seek(0)
...   filename = temp.name
...   session = ftplib.FTP('10.66.118.251','build','password')
...   session.storbinary('STOR {0}'.format(file_name), temp)
...   session.quit()
...   temp.flush()
...
'226 Transfer complete.'
'221 Goodbye.'
>>> print session
<ftplib.FTP instance at 0x3018098>
>>> print session.storbinary()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: storbinary() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

Comment: The `storebinary()` call should return the message of at least the error code.

Comment: so i can do result = storebinary() for example?

Comment: this didnt work "NameError: name 'storebinary' is not defined"